# Why was my location changed to Chandgad, India?

Tags: support

Until just now, I'd never even heard of Chandgad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They did some automatic network wide "improvement" of user locations.
See "[Why does my location in stackoverflow profile change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88217/155585)" on meta.SO. More details can be found in [this meta.SO answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88306/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-correct-format-of-the-user-profiles-location/88320#88320): The Yahoo PlaceFinder thinks that ["Chandgad, India" is a best match for "Here"](http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=here).

Comment: I do like the fact that so many people get relocated to Norway!

Comment: Wow. That is some algorithm. I am now curious what it would match for zed-zed-nine-plural-zed-alpha...

Comment: ... and the answer is, nothing, apparently.

Comment: @Willie: I got "Alpha, MI, United States". Very nice is the answer for ["Somewhere in the vicinity of Sol"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88339/155585).

Comment: So Alpha, MI is preferred over Alpha, NJ? I wonder if it is just alphabetical.